# is there coinmarketcap api error when we try to fetch data from a date range?

Tags: cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap

I'm always getting the same Api error even though I try to search for different range of dates.

HTTP 400
/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/historical?start=2024-03-20&end=2024-03-26&CMC_PRO_API_KEY=(key deleted)

but when I use a search for only one date no errors appear.

I'm currently using Startup plan which I guess it make sense for my script to search into historical data.

I was expecting to get no errors